# Why can I not group sed commands after an address in a block?

Tags: sed

I’m trying to use `sed` to print all lines until but excluding a specific pattern. I don’t understand why the following doesn’t work:

```bsh
sed '/PATTERN/{d;q}' file
```

According to my understanding of sed scripting, this expression should cause the following:

- When a line matches `/PATTERN/`, execute the group consisting of commands to

  1. `d`elete the pattern space (= the current line)
  2. `q`uit after printing the current pattern space

In isolation, both `/PATTERN/d` and `/PATTERN/q` work; that is, `d` deletes the offending line, and `q` causes `sed` to terminate *but after printing the line*, as documented. But grouping the two operations together in a block seemingly causes the `q` to be ignored.

I know that I can use `Q` instead of `{d;q}` as a GNU extension (and this works as expected!) but I’m interested in understanding why the above doesn’t work, and in what way I am misinterpreting the documentation.

---

My actual use-case is (only slightly) more complex, since the first line of the file actually matches the pattern, and I’m skipping that (after doing some replacement):

```bsh
sed -e '1{s/>21/>chr21/; n}' -e '/>/{d;q}' in.fasta >out.fasta
```

But the above, simplified case exhibits the same behaviour.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To output all lines of a file until the matching of a particular pattern (and to *not* output that matching line), you may use

```
sed -n '/PATTERN/q; p;' file
```

Here, the default output of the pattern space at the end of each cycle is disabled with `-n`.  Instead we explicitly output each line with `p`.  If the given pattern matches, we halt processing with `q`.

Your actual, longer, command, which changes the name of chromosome 21 from just `21` to `chr21` on the first line of a fasta file, and then proceeds to extract the DNA for that chromosome until it hits the next fasta header line, may be written as

```sh
sed -n -e '1 { s/^>21/>chr21/p; d; }' \
       -e '/^>/q' \
       -e p <in.fasta >out.fasta
```

or

```sh
sed -n '1 { s/^>21/>chr21/p; d; }; /^>/q; p' <in.fasta >out.fasta
```

The issue with your original expression is that the `d` starts a new cycle (i.e., it forces the next line to be read into the pattern space and there's a jump to the start of the script).  This means `q` would never be executed.

Note that to be syntactically correct on non-GNU systems, your original script should look like `/PATTERN/ { d; q; }`.  Note the added `;` after `q` (the spaces are not significant).

Answer (score 9):

`d` does not just delete the pattern space: from the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

> `[2addr]d`
>
> > Delete the pattern space and *start the next cycle*.

(my emphasis)

The `q` command is unreachable.

Comment: Also, if using a non-GNU `sed`, the command directly before `}` (on the same line) has to be terminated by `;`.

Comment: Oh, apparently I misunderstood what “start the next cycle” means. Is there another way of accomplishing this then, which does not rely on GNU extensions?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same output (only those lines before the first match) by using the two-address form:

```
sed -e '/PATTERN/,$d'
```

But unlike methods using `q`, this means `sed` continues reading every input line.   This can make a difference on large input files, or when reading from a pipe.

Comment: Yeah, I intentionally didn’t do this because my file is hundreds of MiB. But it’s good to have the solution here for completeness.